# Error getting Object from NSDictionary

Tags: json, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsobject

I have the array below

```
(
    (
        "id:19",
        "name:Virgin Club House Heathrow",
        "address:Heathrow Airport, 234 Bath Road, Hayes, Middlesex",
        "postcode:UB3 5AP",
        "latitude:51.48127",
        "longitude:-0.448696"
    ),
        (
        "id:20",
        "name:Le Bilboquet",
        "address:20 E 60th St, New York, United States",
        "postcode:NY 10022",
        "latitude:40.764072",
        "longitude:-73.970834"
    )
)
```

which I am enumerating through using

```
[venuesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary* obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
{
     NSString* tmpStr;
     tmpStr = [obj objectForKey:@"id"];
}];
```

however I'm getting this error -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff26866a690.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, you have an array.  Even though your block is calling the objects it is getting `NSDictionary`, it is being given an array instead.  Use `NSLog` to print out the data type and content of `obj` to debug this.